# How do you calculate variance withing group without using a variance function

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
Name    a   b   c
sam     1   2   3
sam     4   3   2
tom     5   5   2
tom     2   4   7
fred    2   3   5
fred    1   2   3
```

I am using the following query to generate the variance:

```
select  n,sum((b-f)*(b-f))/(count(b)-1) from test,(select name as n,avg(b) as f from test group by name ) as j where j.n==name  group by name ;
```

When I run the query I am getting the following results. Why am I am getting a blank for sam?

```
n       sum((b-f)*(b-f))/(count(b)-1)
fred    0.5
sam 
tom     0.5
```

Comment: wouldn't this query generate an error.  You are grouping by `Name` but you are selecting `n` from the derived table `j`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the symptoms.  Under stock CentOS 6 sqlite 3.6.20, using the interactive interface, I get a row "sam,0.5" using your query.

Comment: This example runs fine in SQLFiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/30473/3).